# DataNucleus relationship fetch group confusion

Tags: postgresql, orm, query-optimization, jdo, datanucleus

All models are here: https://github.com/valentijnscholten/dependency-track/tree/metrics-opt-comp/src/main/java/org/dependencytrack/model

I want to avoid the 1+N queries problem while processing a list of models and accessing a relationship/collection on each of them. This should be easy according to the DataNucleus docs, and is quite common. But it doesn't seem to work as advertised.
When adding the relationship to the fetch group, I can see that DN is doing an extra query to "Bulk Fetch" the relationship. This looks good. But as soon as I actually access the relationship, it does the same query again. But this time specifically for this model instance. So I end up with 1+1+N queries.

Question applies mostly to [Component.java](https://github.com/valentijnscholten/dependency-track/blob/metrics-opt-comp/src/main/java/org/dependencytrack/model/Component.java):

It has a many-to-many relationship (but I see the same problem with 1-N):

```
@Persistent(table = "COMPONENTS_VULNERABILITIES")
@Join(column = "COMPONENT_ID")
@Element(column = "VULNERABILITY_ID")
@Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "id ASC"))
private List<Vulnerability> vulnerabilities;

@FetchGroup(name = "METRICS_UPDATE", members = {
        @Persistent(name = "id"),
        @Persistent(name = "lastInheritedRiskScore"),
        @Persistent(name = "uuid"),
        @Persistent(name = "vulnerabilities"),
        @Persistent(name = "analysises"),
        @Persistent(name = "policyViolations")                
})

Query<Component> query = pm.newQuery(Component.class);
query.setOrdering("id DESC");
query.setRange(0, 500);
query.getFetchPlan().setGroup(Component.FetchGroup.METRICS_UPDATE.name());
query.getFetchPlan().setFetchSize(FetchPlan.FETCH_SIZE_GREEDY);
query.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth(10);
components = query.executeList();

LOGGER.debug("Fetched " + components.size() + " components for project " + project.getUuid());
for (final Component component : components) {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("Printing vulnerabilities count: " + component.getVulnerabilities().stream().count());
```

FetchSize and MaxDepth are added because I was trying stuff.

Logs

```
2023-02-11 18:41:36,458 DEBUG [Query] JDOQL Query : Executing "SELECT FROM org.dependencytrack.model.Component WHERE project == :project ORDER BY id DESC RANGE 0,500" ...
2023-02-11 18:41:36,460 DEBUG [Connection] ManagedConnection OPENED : "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@3a5359fd [conn=com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection@78a8a548, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" on resource "nontx" with isolation level "read-committed" and auto-commit=false
2023-02-11 18:41:36,460 DEBUG [Datastore] Using PreparedStatement "HikariProxyPreparedStatement@289630101 wrapping SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Component' AS "DN_TYPE","A0"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A0"."LAST_RISKSCORE","A0"."UUID" FROM "COMPONENT" "A0" WHERE "A0"."PROJECT_ID" = ? ORDER BY "NUCORDER0" DESC FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY " for connection "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection@78a8a548"
2023-02-11 18:41:36,463 DEBUG [Native] SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Component' AS "DN_TYPE","A0"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A0"."LAST_RISKSCORE","A0"."UUID" FROM "COMPONENT" "A0" WHERE "A0"."PROJECT_ID" = ? ORDER BY "NUCORDER0" DESC FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
2023-02-11 18:41:36,466 DEBUG [Retrieve] SQL Execution Time = 3 ms
2
```

... some other bulk prefetches snipped

```
2023-02-11 18:41:36,476 DEBUG [Retrieve] JDOQL Bulk-Fetch of org.dependencytrack.model.Component.vulnerabilities
2023-02-11 18:41:36,476 DEBUG [Datastore] Using PreparedStatement "HikariProxyPreparedStatement@555511245 wrapping SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Vulnerability' AS "DN_TYPE","A1"."CREATED","A1"."CREDITS","A1"."CVSSV2BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV2EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2VECTOR","A1"."CVSSV3BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV3EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3VECTOR","A1"."CWES","A1"."DESCRIPTION","A1"."DETAIL","A1"."EPSSPERCENTILE","A1"."EPSSSCORE","A1"."FRIENDLYVULNID","A1"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A1"."OWASPRRBUSINESSIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRLIKELIHOODSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRTECHNICALIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRVECTOR","A1"."PATCHEDVERSIONS","A1"."PUBLISHED","A1"."RECOMMENDATION","A1"."REFERENCES","A1"."SEVERITY","A1"."SOURCE","A1"."SUBTITLE","A1"."TITLE","A1"."UPDATED","A1"."UUID","A1"."VULNID","A1"."VULNERABLEVERSIONS","A0"."COMPONENT_ID" FROM "COMPONENTS_VULNERABILITIES" "A0" INNER JOIN "VULNERABILITY" "A1" ON "A0"."VULNERABILITY_ID" = "A1"."ID" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Component' AS "DN_TYPE","A0_SUB"."ID" AS "DN_APPID" FROM "COMPONENT" "A0_SUB" WHERE "A0_SUB"."PROJECT_ID" = ? AND "A0"."COMPONENT_ID" = "A0_SUB"."ID") ORDER BY "NUCORDER0"" for connection "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection@78a8a548"
2023-02-11 18:41:36,476 DEBUG [Native] SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Vulnerability' AS "DN_TYPE","A1"."CREATED","A1"."CREDITS","A1"."CVSSV2BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV2EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2VECTOR","A1"."CVSSV3BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV3EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3VECTOR","A1"."CWES","A1"."DESCRIPTION","A1"."DETAIL","A1"."EPSSPERCENTILE","A1"."EPSSSCORE","A1"."FRIENDLYVULNID","A1"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A1"."OWASPRRBUSINESSIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRLIKELIHOODSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRTECHNICALIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRVECTOR","A1"."PATCHEDVERSIONS","A1"."PUBLISHED","A1"."RECOMMENDATION","A1"."REFERENCES","A1"."SEVERITY","A1"."SOURCE","A1"."SUBTITLE","A1"."TITLE","A1"."UPDATED","A1"."UUID","A1"."VULNID","A1"."VULNERABLEVERSIONS","A0"."COMPONENT_ID" FROM "COMPONENTS_VULNERABILITIES" "A0" INNER JOIN "VULNERABILITY" "A1" ON "A0"."VULNERABILITY_ID" = "A1"."ID" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Component' AS "DN_TYPE","A0_SUB"."ID" AS "DN_APPID" FROM "COMPONENT" "A0_SUB" WHERE "A0_SUB"."PROJECT_ID" = ? AND "A0"."COMPONENT_ID" = "A0_SUB"."ID") ORDER BY "NUCORDER0"
2023-02-11 18:41:36,480 DEBUG [Retrieve] SQL Execution Time = 4 ms
```

As far as I can see this is using the filters from the original query to fetch the vulnerabilities relationship. So far so good.

The first statement after the query above is to access getVulnerabilities(), and this results in, more or less, the exact same query:

```
2023-02-11 18:41:36,494 DEBUG [ProjectMetricsUpdateTask] Fetched 5 components for project f04cfba0-7b94-4380-8cbd-aca492f97a7f
2023-02-11 18:41:36,494 DEBUG [Persistence] Object with id "org.dependencytrack.model.Component:45106" has a lifecycle change : "HOLLOW"->"P_NONTRANS"
2023-02-11 18:41:36,508 DEBUG [Persistence] Object "org.dependencytrack.model.Component@68f46ca4" field "vulnerabilities" is replaced by a SCO wrapper of type "org.datanucleus.store.types.wrappers.backed.List" [cache-values=true, lazy-loading=true, allow-nulls=true]
2023-02-11 18:41:36,508 DEBUG [Persistence] Object "org.dependencytrack.model.Component@68f46ca4" field "vulnerabilities" loading contents to SCO wrapper from the datastore
2023-02-11 18:41:36,512 DEBUG [Connection] ManagedConnection OPENED : "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@73aeb4aa [conn=com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection@30f8bfe1, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" on resource "nontx" with isolation level "read-committed" and auto-commit=false
2023-02-11 18:41:36,512 DEBUG [Datastore] Using PreparedStatement "HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1310502991 wrapping SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Vulnerability' AS "DN_TYPE","A1"."CREATED","A1"."CREDITS","A1"."CVSSV2BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV2EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2VECTOR","A1"."CVSSV3BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV3EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3VECTOR","A1"."CWES","A1"."DESCRIPTION","A1"."DETAIL","A1"."EPSSPERCENTILE","A1"."EPSSSCORE","A1"."FRIENDLYVULNID","A1"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A1"."OWASPRRBUSINESSIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRLIKELIHOODSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRTECHNICALIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRVECTOR","A1"."PATCHEDVERSIONS","A1"."PUBLISHED","A1"."RECOMMENDATION","A1"."REFERENCES","A1"."SEVERITY","A1"."SOURCE","A1"."SUBTITLE","A1"."TITLE","A1"."UPDATED","A1"."UUID","A1"."VULNID","A1"."VULNERABLEVERSIONS" FROM "COMPONENTS_VULNERABILITIES" "A0" INNER JOIN "VULNERABILITY" "A1" ON "A0"."VULNERABILITY_ID" = "A1"."ID" WHERE "A0"."COMPONENT_ID" = ? ORDER BY "NUCORDER0"" for connection "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection@30f8bfe1"
2023-02-11 18:41:36,515 DEBUG [Native] SELECT 'org.dependencytrack.model.Vulnerability' AS "DN_TYPE","A1"."CREATED","A1"."CREDITS","A1"."CVSSV2BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV2EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV2VECTOR","A1"."CVSSV3BASESCORE","A1"."CVSSV3EXPLOITSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3IMPACTSCORE","A1"."CVSSV3VECTOR","A1"."CWES","A1"."DESCRIPTION","A1"."DETAIL","A1"."EPSSPERCENTILE","A1"."EPSSSCORE","A1"."FRIENDLYVULNID","A1"."ID" AS "NUCORDER0","A1"."OWASPRRBUSINESSIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRLIKELIHOODSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRTECHNICALIMPACTSCORE","A1"."OWASPRRVECTOR","A1"."PATCHEDVERSIONS","A1"."PUBLISHED","A1"."RECOMMENDATION","A1"."REFERENCES","A1"."SEVERITY","A1"."SOURCE","A1"."SUBTITLE","A1"."TITLE","A1"."UPDATED","A1"."UUID","A1"."VULNID","A1"."VULNERABLEVERSIONS" FROM "COMPONENTS_VULNERABILITIES" "A0" INNER JOIN "VULNERABILITY" "A1" ON "A0"."VULNERABILITY_ID" = "A1"."ID" WHERE "A0"."COMPONENT_ID" = ? ORDER BY "NUCORDER0"
```

Disabling L2 Cache doesn't help. There are a couple more relationships in the Component class. They all have the samen problem. I also notice that DN only fetches 1 level of relationships, despite the max depth being set to 10.

So two questions:

- Why is the prefetched contents of the relationship not used?
- Why is only 1 level of relationships prefetched?

I do notice that the vulnerabilities relation is empty in the database. Could that be triggering the repeat of queries?